# PHP Curl Not working

Tags: php, curl

I am new here and not a pro in php but need a small help. Actually I was given a code by my service prodvider to upload on my hosting. But when i uploaded that code on my hosting account it didnt work well and after contact the support I was told to use php curl code in some part to make it run. can anyone please help me with the issue.

Original Code:

```
<?php

$MobileNumber=substr($_REQUEST['VerifiedNumber'],-10);

$APIKey="<Your Dial2verify API Key Here>";
$SenderID="<6 ALPHABETIC CHARACTERS ONLY>";
$Message="<Your SMS Text Here>";

echo `curl -XPOST "http://host/SMS/SEND/$APIKey/$SenderID/$MobileNumber" -d "Msg=$Message"`;

?>
```

I don't know how to make the above code into curl code to make it work.

Thanks :)

Comment: You are using curl from command line with your code. The support tells you curl but they mean CURL for PHP ;) See the doc php.net/curl to know how to use the php's extension.

Comment: @Akuti, Please first check CURL is installed or not ! <?php phpinfo();
?> & also you written code of command line.

Comment: Show us your error/warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it did not work was that you where trying to call the command line version of cURL (and also doing the call wrong).

The best way is to use the php cURL module to make this call. Verify first that it is installed by creating an info.php file with the contents

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

If cURL is present on that page you are good to go.

Obviously I have not had the ability to test this code but something like this should work

```
$msisdn   = substr($_REQUEST['VerifiedNumber'],-10);
$apiKey   = "<Your Dial2verify API Key Here>";
$senderId = "<6 ALPHABETIC CHARACTERS ONLY>";
$message  = "<Your SMS Text Here>";

$url = "http://host/SMS/SEND/$apiKey/$senderId/$msisdn";

$ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('Msg' => $message));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo 'Response from server:';
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Hi Sir,

I tried using the above code but its giving an error "Error 523 Ray ID"

Comment: This is an [error from CloudFlare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200171946-Error-523). The server you are trying to reach is protected by them. From the error message it looks like the origin server is having a problem.

Comment: But sir when i used the default code it was saying saying "{"APIStatus":"Error: Recipient number should be 10 digit Indian phone number"}" but when i used the code you gave me the error was the error 523

Comment: I see now that there is an error in the code. Replace `array('Msg' => message)` with `array('Msg' => $message)`

Comment: As you said i replaced the code with the one you gave. Now this is the error log 

[31-Oct-2014 02:48:05 America/Denver] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: VerifiedNumber in /home3/success.php on line 3
[31-Oct-2014 02:48:10 America/Denver] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: VerifiedNumber in /home3/success.php on line 3
[31-Oct-2014 02:48:11 America/Denver] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: VerifiedNumber in /home3/success.php on line 3

Comment: That is because you are not sending in the number to the script. Lets say your file is called send.php, you need to call it like `send.php?VerifiedNumber=9938857288`

Comment: Actually its a kind of service when a customer give a miss call and he/she will get a message on it number.. and as you said i need to call it.. but from my phone i gave a miss call but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

By using `, you are using CURL via command line.

1st, check if the CURL extension for php is installed properly on you environment. Check if something about CURL is available when you print `<?php phpinfo();?>`

2nd, if CURL is installed, check on php.net/curl to know how to use CURL.

Here a simple example to call your webservice :

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.host.com/SMS/SEND/$APIKey/$SenderID/$MobileNumber");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"Msg=This+is+my+text+message");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$reply = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);


echo $reply;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply sir, i have checked curl is enabled on php.
i still dont get what about these options 

$MobileNumber=substr($_REQUEST['VerifiedNumber'],-10);

$APIKey="<Your Dial2verify API Key Here>";
$SenderID="<6 ALPHABETIC CHARACTERS ONLY>";